# How to change certain variables in configuration file during the execution of the script?

Tags: bash, sed, m4

I have a bash script which starts from [cron](https://www.gnu.org/software/mcron/) with regular interval and sources in around 10 variables from a file at the beginning of the script. Some of those variables might change during the execution of the script and I need to store those in configuration file. Variables are in a file and separated with newline. For example:

```
$ cat conf
var1="cat"
var2="dog"
var3="hamster"
$
```

What is the best practice to change certain variables in conf file during the execution of the script? I could use `sed`. For example let's say that during the execution of the script variable named `var2` has assigned a new value `fish`, i.e `var2=fish`. In this case I could update the `conf` file with `sed`:

```
sed -i "s/var2=\".*\"/var2=\""$var2"\"/" conf
```

As a next option, I could gather all the variables at the end of the script and overwrite the file with:

```
cat > conf << EOF
var1="$var1"
var2="$var2"
var3="$var3"
EOF
```

I also looked into `m4`, but I couldn't figure out if it is possible to use it in my scenario because the value of variable changes during the execution of the script, e.g following obviously can not work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

. conf

# Initial value of var2 was "dog".
# Now it is replaced with "fish".
var2=fish

m4 -D"$var2"="$var2" conf
```

Comment: If you are going to double-quote the sed expression and suffer needing to slash-escape the inner double-quotes then at least don't drop out of the quotes to embed the variable (i.e. `"s/var2=\".*\"/var2=\"$var2\"/"`). Alternatively use single-quotes around the non-variable contents instead and avoid needing to escape the inner quotes (i.e.`'s/var2=".*"/var2="'"$var2"'"/'`). Also *do* quote the expansion of the variable.

Comment: Whatever option you choose you want to make sure it is atomic. Which means `sed -i` or something else that offers atomic in-place operation or a temporary file and an atomic `mv`.

Comment: I would use [tag:awk].

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks for this single-quotes around the non-variable contents trick! By atomic you mean that when I open my `conf` file for writing no other process can write to this file at that time? As I understand, `sed -i` example in my example in my initial post was an atomic operation?

Comment: By atomic I meant that you need to be sure your process either replaces the entire file contents or doesn't modify the file at all (writing to the file a line at a time can get interrupted/etc. and lose data). Yes, I believe `sed -i` is atomic (as I said in my previous comment).

Answer (score 1):

### awk

Use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), it's fairly simple:

```
awk -F '=' -v varname="var1" -v varvalue="$var1" '$1 == varname { $2 = "\""varvalue"\"" } { print }' conf
```

You could simply loop over all variables too, supplying them as arguments using the `-v` option. The script will look for variable names before a `=` symbol and replace the value of the mapped value by the new value. If the name is not found, nothing happens.

Note that this could fail if a variable name contained a equals symbol but this is not allowed and hence no problem.

### Caution

Watch out when you are saving variables that contain double quotes. Say you have `var2="some text containing "double quotes"'`. Putting this in your `conf` file will be dangerous!

Comment: Thanks for this `awk` example. However, does it have any advantages over for example `sed -i`?

Comment: No not really. I just think it's more readable and understandable. If you would like to extend it's functionality you'll have an easier time doing it with this [tag:awk] script then with a [tag:sed] script. Your `[tag:cat] options is just as ok although you'd need a ton of lines if the number of variables grows while you could use a for loop with the awk script.

Comment: Don't you need `"\""varvalue"\""` there? (But `printf` or `sprintf` is probably better.)